# Which is the correct/better way to represent the following argument?

Tags: logic

p1. If an omni-god exists, then evil cannot exist

p2. evil exists

c. an omni-god does not exist

I'm pretty sure its modus tollens and is represented as follows,

p -> q

¬q

¬p

But my friend is representing it as,

p -> ¬q

q

¬p

which one is correct? are they both?

Comment: I agree with your friend. That version makes “can do evil” an affirmative statement, then negates it. I see this as cleaner, and easier to think about, than assuming  a negative.

Comment: First note that the negation of "cannot" is "can" so the negation of "evil cannot exist" is "evil can exist" rather than "p2. evil exists".  Having said that, I think that your choice of the form *modus tolens* is the more natural choice considering the context.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, Nick R, I think my friend is getting confused by the 'cannot' in the conditional statement, thinking that it must mean a negation.

Comment: @NickR, you should expand this into a real answer.  Anyone else answering the question will look like they are copying from you even if they did think of it independently.

Comment: Both arguments are fine, but the premises are weak so the conclusion will unlikely convince anyone who does not already believe it.  See the logical problem of evil: https://www.iep.utm.edu/evil-log/ for what people have tried in the past. In particular look at Plantinga's objections.

Answer (score 1):

The one is ((p → q) & ~q) →  ~p and other is ((p → ~q) & q) →  ~p. Replace q by ~q. The first is the second or the second is the first. Because of this, they are the same. Neither is better than the other. (And the "p → q" is false according to the Gospel, cause "~p" is invalid. So they are also the same, but both are in error.)

The "an omni-god exists" is God shall be Godself by His own Will to Life; "evil cannot exist" is God forbids every evil in the world; and, "evil exists" is evil is allowed to come in the world (as Satan was allowed to tempt Job to show Job's faith). So the whole proof has the logic ((O(p) → O(~q)) & ~O(~q)) → ~O(p)). [The (O(p) → O(~q) is also false according to the Bible. God, to be Godself, need not clean every evil from the world until the last day.]

Comment: The question is not about whether p1 is true.  The question is about how best to represent the logic of this reasoning.

Comment: I made an edit for clarity. You may roll this back or continue editing. Best wishes.